# XPATH expression to get local name and namespace of XML attribute of datatype QName

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to display XML document with XSLT by following this example from w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xsl.asp. The XSLT transformation to HTML will be done in the browser when opening the XML document.

Now, I have difficulties a) getting the local name and 2) getting the namespace of the attribute content of type QName in two separate expressions.

**Example**

```
<service xmlns:ns3="http://www.mycompany.com/" name="ns3:PersonService">
    <serviceInterface name="ns3:PersonServiceInterface">
         <operation>...</operation>
</serviceInterface>
```

**Questions**

1. What XPATH expression will return **PersonService** as content of attribute *name*? `<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>` returns **ns3:PersonService** but i don't want the namespace prefix.
2. What XPATH expression will return **http://www.mycompany.com/** as the namespace of the attribute *name*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.What XPATH expression will return PersonService as content of attribute name?

**Assuming that `service` is a child of the top element (you haven't provided a complete and well-formed XML document), use**:

```
substring-after(/*/service/@name, ':')
```

> 2.What XPATH expression will return http://www.mycompany.com/ as the namespace of the attribute name?

**Under the same assumptions as above, use:**

```
/*/service/namespace::*[name() = substring-before(../@name, ':')]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(/*/service/@name, ':')"/>
============
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "/*/service/namespace::*[name() = substring-before(../@name, ':')]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**this XSLT transformation, when applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, but completed):

```
<t>
    <service xmlns:ns3="http://www.mycompany.com/"
             name="ns3:PersonService">
        <serviceInterface name="ns3:PersonServiceInterface">
            <operation>...</operation>
        </serviceInterface>
    </service>
</t>
```

**evaluates the two XPath expressions and copies the results of these evaluations to the output:**

```
PersonService
============
http://www.mycompany.com/
```

Comment: Dimitre, thank you very much. This was exactly what I needed, and it worked! But are there no XPATH functions that makes it easier to retrieve this information?

Comment: @IsmarSlomic, Why do you think that "there are no XPATH functions that makes it easier to retrieve this information?". We use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()`. We also use the `namespace::` axis and the `name()` function.

Comment: Dimitre, you are right of course. What I ment was why there are noen XPATH function where you can just pass the node/attribute and get the local name/namespace.

Comment: @IsmarSlomic, If you can use XPath 2.0 (with XSLT 2.0 or XQuery), then the following XPath 2.0 - only functions can be useful: `prefix-from-QName()`, `local-name-from-QName()`, `namespace-uri-from-QName()`, `namespace-uri-for-prefix()`